# Reading Foxpro files (.DBF) from PHP/Linux

Tags: php, linux, foxpro

Is it possible to read locally available Foxpro files (.DBF) from a PHP script hosted on a Linux server?

Please suggest anything that doesn't depend on Windows or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php has an extension for reading dbf files: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php

Comment: Thank you. Could I download the extension file from somewhere instead of compiling it from source?

Comment: I made a quick google search and this site describes how to solve exactly the problem you have: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/phpextensions.html. It looks like you will have to compile the extension, but you can load it as a dynamic extension afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I built dbase.so, thanks to http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/09/14/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/ (except the first step where I had to use a command like "yum install php-devel"

Answer (score 0):

Various utilities are available for dumping DBF data to CSV and similar formats, E.g.: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbfdump .

Or you can invoke Open Office base (in headless mode) to convert data to CSV.